# Where should I ask a question about a tree that was found on a trail but could be in a yard?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I'm seeking information about what appears to be a severe problem affecting the bark of two trees, which I think are birches.

The trees were found by my husband on a hike in the woods, but they don't look much different than those I've seen in yards, including my own. My friend and I both have birches, some of which look like they could be headed in that direction.

The question would ask for things including

- identification and diagnosis of the problem
- the likelihood of the same issue affecting trees in neighborhood landscapes, whether birch or not
- direct contagion to nearby trees, again whether birch or not
- potential preventative measures
- availability and recommendations for treatment if caught early

I have two pictures of the trees, but none of the surrounding environment. My husband's not likely to see them again, so I wouldn't be able to answer any of the usual follow-up questions we ask here.

Because they were found out in the woods, I think the alternative site would be [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/). I would probably receive a diagnosis, as many hikers understand these trees and what affects them. However, relating them to our own trees may be off topic there, and also better answered here.

I've asked tree-related questions on both sites. The three here, which are  [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16070/), [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/), and [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/) elicited helpful answers about my own trees, some of which we've since removed.

The two at TGO were asked to gain knowledge of things I'd never before seen on trees out on a trail. The answers were interesting and helpful.

I'm trying to avoid a migration issue, and this question might be in a gray area, so I thought I'd ask here before posting it anywhere!

Answer (score 4):

All aspects of your proposed question look on-topic to me.

The initial hurdle appears to be the fact that the trees were in the woods, not in your garden, but we have other questions about stuff found in the wild. A couple of well-upvoted examples spring to mind (there are others):

- [What is this large, woody plant with compound leaves, found in zone 6a?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16197/what-is-this-large-woody-plant-with-compound-leaves-found-in-zone-6a)
- [What is this woody plant with spicy, citrus flavored twigs?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14533/what-is-this-woody-plant-with-spicy-citrus-flavored-twigs)
- [What is this small white spathed plant in southeast Pennsylvania woodland?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13328/what-is-this-small-white-spathed-plant-in-southeast-pennsylvania-woodland)

Given that we allow questions about plants that aren't in a garden, it's an easy step from there to diagnosis of a problem with them, which should lead you to possible treatments of the problem.